# Understanding an exercise (Ahlfors' Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have two questions about the solution of the following exercise, taken from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis.

1. In the first integral of the first equality, why is it equivalent to integrate along the curve $|z|=2$ to integrate along the curve $|z+1|=1$? And similarly for the second integral, but considering the curve $|z-1|=1$. I understand they're changing the original circle by a circle centered at the points $-1$ and $1$ and contained in $|z|=2$, but I can't find the theorem or result they're using to do so.
2. Why are they doing that change? Isn't it enough to say that both integrals along the original curve $|z|=2$ equal $2\pi i$ by the Cauchy's integral formula?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to point 1. If two cycles are homologous then their integrals will be the same. The cycle formed by the one circle $|z|=2$ is homologous to the one formed by the two smaller circles so the step works. I referred to the Real and Complex analysis by Walter Rudin. theorem 10.35 for the details on this.

For point 2, I think you are right. Integrating $\frac{1}{z-1}$ over $|z|=2$ or$|z-1|=1$ should give the same result as both circles are homologous so this step seems redundant.

Comment: But is it easier to get the integral along a circle centered at the point? Or why do they do the change?

Comment: Well if you already know how to calculate the integral of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ around on circle containing $a$ then the particular circle you choose doesn't matter. If you actually want to compute it using a parametrisation then choosing a unit radius circle with $a$ as the origin is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading Ahlfors and it's strange that in the section of this exercise he hasn't talked about homology. But this solution is taken from a PDF from the internet, so maybe they used it.

Comment: Basically, if you can smoothly deform a curve into another one without pulling it over any holes in the domain of the function, then the integral of the function will be the same for both curves.

Comment: Alright. What seems strange to me is that the person who wrote this solution decided to use a more advanced tool instaed of simply using Cauchy's integral formula for the circle $|z|=2$.

Comment: I agree that it is strange- why assume that the person following knows about deforming curves but not that the integral of each part will be the same for $|z|=2$? That got me confused as well.

Comment: Unless there's another explanation...